# Doubt in proving differentiable when both partial derivatives are equal

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I had a problem with a step in this:

I have to prove that:

**$|xy|^{\alpha}$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ if $\alpha > \frac{1}{2}$**.

In this case both partial derivatives exist and have the value $0$.then the next step says:
$|xy|^{\alpha}$ is differentiable iff the following is true:

$$ \lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{|xy|^{\alpha}}{\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}} = 0$$

I can't understand why this should be true i.e. why does above limit hold....

Please help...

Comment: Do you know the definition of differentiability for a two variable function?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 the definition of differentiabilty for 2-/more variable:  a function $f:A\to Y$ is said to be differentiable if there is a linear map:$T\in L(X,Y)$,such that:   $lim_{r\to 0}\frac{\|f(a+r)-f(a)-Tr\|}{\|r\|}=0$

Comment: Just to be clear, are you asking why is that function differentiable iff that limit is 0, or are you asking why that limit is 0?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 I'm asking why is that function differentiable iff that limit is 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's apply that definition here.

$f : X \to Y$ is said to be differentiable at $a$ iff there is a linear map $T \in L(X,Y)$ such that $$\displaystyle\lim_{r \to 0}\dfrac{\|f(a+r)-f(a)-Tr\|}{\|r\|} = 0$$

In this problem, the domain is $X = \mathbb{R}^2$, the range is $Y = \mathbb{R}$, and our point of interest is $a = (0,0)$.

Since both partials were $0$, the linear map (if the function is differentiable) must be $T(x,y) = 0$.

Letting $r = (x,y) \to (0,0)$ we have that $f(x,y) = |xy|^{\alpha}$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ iff $$\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \dfrac{|f(x,y)-f(0,0)-T(x,y)|}{\|(x,y)\|} = 0$$

i.e. $$\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \dfrac{|xy|^{\alpha}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = 0$$

which is what the problem tells you that you need to show.

Comment: thanks for the answer...but can you please help me understanding how you chose the linear map to be $0$...please help ..

Comment: If we have a function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$, then the matrix $T$ which works is given by $T_{ij} = \dfrac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}$. This is known as the Jacobian matrix. In this case, we have a function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^1$, so the Jacobian is a $1 \times 2$ matrix with entries $T_{11} = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 0$ and $T_{12} = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0$. Hence. the linear map is the $0$ map.

Answer (score 2):

If $x=(x_1,x_2)$, you have $|x_k| \le \|x\|$, so
${ |x_1 x_2|^\alpha \over \|x\|} \le { \|x\|^{2 \alpha} \over \|x\|}= \|x\|^{2 \alpha -1}$.

Noting htat $2 \alpha >1$, we have $\lim_{ x \to 0} { |x_1 x_2|^\alpha \over \|x\|} = 0$.